# why can not i finished repl :pas model with ctrl + d

Tags: scala, read-eval-print-loop

I used windows 7 and Scala 2.11.11  but when I wrote multiline into REPL,I could not finish it with Ctrl + d
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about the Scala REPL, but according to https://superuser.com/questions/291224/equivalent-to-d-in-bash-for-cmd-exe, the equivalent to <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> in CMD is <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> (you might have to press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> afterwards)